# Using untangle, how can I check the existence of attributes and tags in XML before parsing

Tags: python, xml

I'm parsing an XML file via `untangle` in python and and writing the content to a database.

The content of children tags will be variant for different tags. For example first event tag has party tag as child but second event tag doesn't have.

--> How can I check whether a tag exists or not before parsing?
Currently my code throws an error for non existing party tag and sets a `None`

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Title'
```

Comment: if "needed_tag_str" in child.tag: than print child.tag[needed_tag_str]....but create a dummy xml file, post your code, tell us your result and Expection

Comment: EAFP: can't you just catch the exception and handle missing tags accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

According to untangle github, one alternative is to use `dir` in the node that you know that will always be there. Example (from an issue in their github):

```py
>>> x = untangle.parse('<doc><node-with-title><title>test</title></node-with-title><node-no-title></node-no-title></doc>')
>>> dir(x.doc.node_with_title)
[u'title']
>>> dir(x.doc.node_no_title)
[]
>>> 'title' in dir(x.doc.node_with_title)
True
>>> 'title' in dir(x.doc.node_no_title)
False
```

Source:
https://github.com/stchris/untangle/issues/37

Answer (score -1):

```
        <Program programId="c fragmentVersion="14755725670045441" >
            <Description>
                <ShortTitle xml:lang="en-US" length="9">Max Steel</ShortTitle>
                <Synopsis xml:lang="en-US" length="short">The adventures of .</Synopsis>
                <Synopsis xml:lang="en-US" length="medium">The adventures bo-charged superhero</Synopsis>
                <CreditsList>
                    <CreditsItem role="urn:eventis:metadata:cs:RoleCS:2010:CONTENT-PROVIDER">
                        <OrganizationName xml:lang="en-US">SeaChange</OrganizationName>
                    </CreditsItem>
                    <CreditsItem role="urn:eventis:metadata:cs:RoleCS:2010:CONTENT-PROVIDER-ID">
                        <OrganizationName xml:lang="en-US">seachange.com</OrganizationName>
                    </CreditsItem>
                </CreditsList>
                <RelatedMaterial>
                    <HowRelated href="urn:eventis:metadata:cs:HowRelatedCS:2010:poster"/>
                    <MediaLocator>
                        <MediaUri xmlns="udoster.jpg</MediaUri>
                    </MediaLocator>
                </RelatedMaterial>
                <RelatedMaterial>
                    <HowRelated href="urn:eventis:metadata:cs:HowRelatedCS:2010:boxCover"/>
                    <MediaLocator>
                        <MediaUri xmlns="urn:tva:mpeg7:2008">dover.jpg</MediaUri>
                    </MediaLocator>
                </RelatedMaterial>
                <ProductionDate>
                    <TimePoint>2016</TimePoint>
                </ProductionDate>
                <Duration>22110</Duration>
            </Description>
        </Program>
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit you original post with this sample XML. Then delete this answer.